# Running script with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, script

I'd like to run the script below whenever I run Chrome. The script clears various Chrome settings, and I'd like the setting to be cleared whenever I run Chrome. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ryan

Edit: If there is a better place to post this question please let me know, I'm new here.

Script:

```
set ChromeDataDir=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
set ChromeCache=%ChromeDataDir%\Cache
del /q /s /f "%ChromeCache%\*.*" 
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*Cookies*.*"
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*"
```

New Script:

```
set ChromeDataDir=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
set ChromeCache=%ChromeDataDir%\Cache
del /q /s /f "%ChromeCache%\*.*" 
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*Cookies*.*"
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*"
timeout 1 /nobreak
start Chrome
```

Comment: Why not save as a bat which then starts chrome

Comment: What about something like this?

Comment: Don't ask me  I suggested something, only you know if it will suffice. Remember this is a Q and A site so if that is right is suggest you post it as an answer

Comment: @Dave what happens if Chrome is opened via external link? The script would not be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to run your sequence of commands before the Chrome browser launches *and* after it exits, so you can be assured your systems cleaned if Chrome crashes.

Right click on an empty spot on your Desktop, and choose **New** then **Text Document** which will take you to Notepad (unless you changed your default text editor). Then, type in these commands:

```
set ChromeDataDir=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default  
set ChromeCache=%ChromeDataDir%\Cache  
del /q /s /f "%ChromeCache%\*.*"   
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*Cookies*.*"  
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*"  
chrome  
timeout 10 /nobreak  
del /q /s /f "%ChromeCache%\*.*"   
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*Cookies*.*"  
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*"
```

Why the [TIMEOUT](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) after Chrome exits? Well, Chrome's doing a lot when it closes, so giving it 10 seconds to finish everything helps make sure it's really closed before the cache, cookies, and history is cleared.

Save and close the file, then right-click it, and rename it to CLEANCHROME.BAT (or anything ending in **.BAT**).

Comment: Changed the script with a timeout and to start Chrome at the end with the start command. Any ideas why the script wouldn't be deleting my history? I Google searched the string "blah blah blah", closed Chrome, ran the script to start it again. This should have earased my history/cookies/cache, but when I typed "b" into the search my blah blah blah string came up. Any ideas there?

Comment: Sorry, don't know why %ChromeDataDir% isn't where your cache is.

Comment: That is where my cache is, it deletes the cache fine. But there must be some other history or cache file somewhere that keeps a record. I don't even use Chrome so I'm not sure why I'm doing all this, lol. Thanks for the help anyway.